# I am getting the error in loopback 4 framework. How to solve this error?

Tags: node.js, loopback4

(method) MyUserService.convertToUserProfile(user: User): UserProfile
Convert the user returned by verifyCredentials() to a common user profile that describes a user in your application

```
Property 'convertToUserProfile' in type 'MyUserService' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'UserService<User, Credentials>'.
  Type '(user: import("d:/lb4/lllog/test/src/models/user.model").User) => import("d:/lb4/lllog/test/node_modules/@loopback/authentication/dist/types").UserProfile' is not assignable to type '(user: import("d:/lb4/lllog/test/src/models/user.model").User) => import("d:/lb4/lllog/test/node_modules/@loopback/security/dist/types").UserProfile'.
    Property '[securityId]' is missing in type 'import("d:/lb4/lllog/test/node_modules/@loopback/authentication/dist/types").UserProfile' but required in type 'import("d:/lb4/lllog/test/node_modules/@loopback/security/dist/types").UserProfile'.ts(2416)
types.d.ts(12, 5): '[securityId]' is declared here.
Peek Problem
No quick fixes available
```

Comment: Can you please share your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try some thing like this ?

```html
convertToUserProfile(user: User): UserProfile {
    return {
      id: user.id,
      name: '<' + user.email + '>' + user.name,
      [securityId]: user.id,
    };
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem the solution is to import securityId from loopback security.

import {securityId, UserProfile} from '@loopback/security';

Comment: Hello, it seems you are new here, welcome! The answer your posted is not an answer to the question. If there is something you want to add to the question that would help clarifying/solving the problem, please post it as a comment under the question.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution

```
import {securityId, UserProfile} from '@loopback/security';


return {
      id: user.id,
      name: user.name,
      [securityId]: `${user.id}`
    }
```